# C言語だとコンパイルエラー（ポインタの使い方がよろしくない...？）

Tags: ruby, c

Always I am indebted.
Rubyでは期待通りの出力できたのですが、C言語では考え通りにはならないです。

Rubyで作成したものと、C言語で作成したものを
下記の通り添付致しますので、ご確認の程よろしくお願い致します。
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
■問題
setup i a ・・・ 変数iに値  a を代入する (i=1,2)
addition a・・・ 変数1の値 +a を計算し、計算結果を変数 2 に代入する
subtract a・・・ 変数1の値 -a を計算し、計算結果を変数 2 に代入する

■入力例
4
setup 1 20 
setup 2 40 
addition 40
subtract -20

■期待出力例
20 
40
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

Ruby

```
t = gets.to_i

a=0,0

t.times{
    ary = gets.chomp.split(' ')
        if ary[0] == "setup"
            s = ary[1].to_i
            n = ary[2].to_i
            a[s-1] = n
        elsif ary[0] == "addition"
           x = ary[1].to_i
           a[1] = a[0] + x 
        elsif ary[0] == "subtract"
            y = ary[1].to_i
            a[1] = a[0] - y 
        end
}
puts a.join(' ')
```

C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char ary[3];
    int a[2];
    char t;
    scanf("%s",&t);

    for(int j=0; j<t; j++) {
        if(strcmp(t,"setup")==0) {
            int s = ary[1];
            int n = ary[2];
            n = a[s-1];
        } 
        else if(strcmp(t,"addition")==0) {
            int x = ary[1];
            a[1] =(a[0] + x);
        } 
        else if(strcmp(t,"subtract")==0) {
            int y = ary[1];
            a[1] =(a[0] - y);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "初心者"ということ自体は質問者の技量を見るための指標にはなりますが、タイトルには含めず本文中に含めてください。タイトルは問題となっている部分が簡潔に分かるようにするのが望ましいです。また、前回の質問と同じようなタイトルなので、可能であればもう少し問題点を具体的にしていただきたいです。

Comment: C でなきゃダメですか？ C++ でよければちょっとだけ楽できるんですけど。

Comment: 投稿に当たっては一度ヘルプの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) にも目を通してもらえればと思います。 / コンパイルエラーが出るならそのこともきちんと本文で説明しましょう。ざっと見る限りでは**変数の型**が意識されていないように見えます。

Comment: パッとみて。・a と aryが初期化されてない ・文字列の比較はstrcmpなどを使いましょう ・int n = ary[2]; の n が未使用。・printf("%d\n",a); は a のアドレスが印字されます

Comment: あなたのC言語のコードをRubyと同じように走らせようと思ったら、元のコードと同じところは半分も残りませんでした…。待っていればどなたか親切な方が回答を書いてくれると思いますが、今のあなたのコードを見る限り、すぐに理解できるとは思えません。配列とポインタ、C言語での文字列の取り扱い方など、良いテキストを探して学習し直してから再度この課題に挑戦することをお勧めしておきます。

Comment: コンパイルエラーを問題(=質問)として扱うなら、最低限どんなエラーが出ているのかを質問文に含めましょう。コンパイルエラーになるのはC言語の文法に沿っていないからで、Rubyのコードはあまり関係が無いですよね？(あくまで入出力の仕様にのみ注目すべき)

Answer (score 3):

回答になっていませんが、コメント欄に書くには長すぎるので回答欄を使います。
大きい誤りは３点。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) においては実は文字列という型はありません（ [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ならあるんですが）。 [c](/questions/tagged/c) で文字列を扱うには「 `char` の配列」を使います。提示 [c](/questions/tagged/c) ソースは「 `char` へのポインタ」型が文字列であるかのごとくに誤解があり要修正です（配列とポインタは同じように使えてしまいますが全く違うもの）。配列の大きさは配列定義時点で決まってしまう、というか、決めなきゃならない仕様なので「任意長の文字列を読み込む」（実行時点で文字数が動的に変化する）ことは簡単にはできないのです。そのため、最大 `N` 文字の文字列を読み込む、で代用するしかありません（ないしは動的メモリ確保を使って任意長文字列を扱うか）。

更に [c](/questions/tagged/c) において `"setup"` とソースコード上に書くと文字列リテラルになるのは良いのですが、式の値は「先頭文字へのポインタ右辺値」に変換されるという仕様なのです。そのため、文字列の一致比較は `==` ではダメなんです。ユーザー入力を読み取った `char` 配列の先頭文字へのポインタ右辺値と、文字列リテラル `"setup"` の先頭文字へのポインタ右辺値は、絶対に一致することはありません。なので `strcmp()` という関数を使え、という解説は [c](/questions/tagged/c) の教科書には必ず載っています。

あと `ary` に文字列を読み込む部分が無いですよね。

以上３点を直すと動くわけですが、分量的には全面書き換えになってしまいます。オイラが書き換え後ソースコードを書いて提示してもいいんですけど、せっかくの演習ですしオイラの指摘事項を読んで修正し自己回答してみてください。 SO では自己回答は大いに歓迎されています。

んで、オイラのこの指摘事項が理解できないようなら入門書を買ったりするとよいでしょうね。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/196866 にて同じような質問がされていて同じような回答＝もっと勉強しなさいがついています。掲示板 Q&A サイトはチャットではないので「こうしました→もっと修正して」みたいなやりとりには向きません。とりあえず `char` １個には１文字しか格納できないので、その辺の理解が先っす。あと `ary` を入力するところが無いの変わってませんよね。

Comment: [tag:ruby] コードにある `gets.chomp` 相当の処理が [tag:c] のほうには入っていません。で、コメント欄はチャット欄ではありませんから、コメント欄での Q&A はこれ以上しませんので承知おきください。